# Como eleminar espacios y caracteres especiales en un arreglo

Tags: javascript

Debe ser usado desestructuraccion para completar el ejercicio
Nombres de variables y funciones en ingles y descriptivo

```js
const game = [{
    videogame: `The le!@#$%^&**gend of zelda, Ocarine of time`,
    business: `Nintendo`,
    launch:` 21 de noviembre de 1998`,
    gender: `Aventura`,

},{
    videogame: `Minecraft Classic` ,
    business:`Mojang Studios`,
    launch:`18 de     noviembre de 2011`,
    gender:`Avent  ura`,

},{
    videogame:` Street &!@#Fighter`,
    business:`Nintendo`,
    launch: `30 de agosto de 1987`,
    gender:`Accion`,

}
]

const videogame = (game) => {
    game.map(({videogame, business, launch, gender}) => { console.log(`La empresa ${business}, publico el videojuego ${videogame} en el año ${launch} y es del genero de ${gender}`)})    
};
videogame(game)

const filtergame = (game) =>{ 
    for (const resultfilter of game) {
        
        let { videogame,gender } = resultfilter;
        
        if (gender  === `Accion`) {
          console.log(`El juego${videogame} es de ${gender}`);
        } 
      }

};
filtergame(game)
```

como se puede apreciar en el código necesito borrar espacios y caracteres especiales, ya realice todo lo que se me pide menos eso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para eliminar espacios usa:

```
str.replace(/\s/g, '')
```

Para eliminar caracteres especiales:

```
str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, '')
```

Pero en tu caso me parece que en realidad lo que deseas no es eliminar los caracteres especiales si no los que no sean alfanumericos y los espacios, en este caso puedes usar:

```
str.replace(/[^\w]/gi, '')
```

Si solo deseas los caracteres que sean alfanumericos y mantener los espacios usa:

```
  str.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '')
```

---

Ejemplo:

```js
const game = [{
    videogame: `The le!@#$%^&**gend of zelda, Ocarine of time`,
    business: `Nintendo`,
    launch:` 21 de noviembre de 1998`,
    gender: `Aventura`,

},{
    videogame: `Minecraft Classic` ,
    business:`Mojang Studios`,
    launch:`18 de     noviembre de 2011`,
    gender:`Avent  ura`,

},{
    videogame:` Street &!@#Fighter`,
    business:`Nintendo`,
    launch: `30 de agosto de 1987`,
    gender:`Accion`,

}
]

const videogame = (game) => {
    game.map(({videogame, business, launch, gender}) => { console.log(`La empresa ${business}, publico el videojuego ${videogame} en el año ${launch} y es del genero de ${gender}`.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, ''))})    
};
videogame(game)

const filtergame = (game) =>{ 
    for (const resultfilter of game) {
        
        let { videogame,gender } = resultfilter;
        
        if (gender  === `Accion`) {
          console.log(`El juego${videogame} es de ${gender}`.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, ''));
        } 
      }

};
filtergame(game)
```

Comment: Pensé en poner el pattern \w, pero este permite el caracter guión bajo _, entonces preferí especificar los caracteres que se deseen eliminar para así tener la opción de conservar aquellos caracteres que se quieran y los que no borrarlos

Comment: gracias a sido de mucha ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Puedes realizarlo con los pattern y el replace.

Si deseas es reducir los espacios en ves de reemplazarlos todos, hacemos el proceso en 2 pasos

Primero creamos una varibale que contendrá nuestro pattern o lo podemos manejar directamente en el replace, como primer parámetro, en el segundo parámetros colocamos el valor por el que deseamos reemplazar el simbolo, en este caso es vacio

```
var foo = 'asdfhgh!';

// Aqui indicamos los simbolos que queremos remover de nuestro texto
var pattern = /[\^*@!"#$%&/()=?¡!¿'\\]/gi;

// Removemos los simbolos segun la regla
foo = foo.replace(pattern, '');
console.log(foo);
```

Como segundo paso, para no eliminar todos los espacios sino conservar un espacio entre palábra, realizamos un split, filter y join de la siguiente manera:

```
var foo = 'asdfhgh!             gfrggthg             hoighoigthtr ghthtrr';

// Se realiza un split al texto y se filtra que solo se retorne las posiciones que contengan informacion
var arrFoo = foo.split(' ').filter(i => i !== '');

// unimos las palabras para formar el parrafo con 1 espaciado entre palabras
foo = arrFoo.join(' ');
console.log(foo);
```

De esta manera dejo el código funcional de ambas partes a continuación:

```js
var foo = 'The          le!@#$%^&**gend of zelda,           Ocarine of time';

// Aqui indicamos los simbolos que queremos remover de nuestro texto
var pattern = /[\^*@!"#$%&/()=?¡!¿'\\]/gi;

// Removemos los simbolos segun la regla
foo = foo.replace(pattern, '');
console.log('Removemos los simbolos', foo);

// Se realiza un split al texto y se filtra que solo se retorne las posiciones que contengan informacion
var arrFoo = foo.split(' ').filter(i => i !== '');

// unimos las palabras para formar el parrafo con 1 espaciado entre palabras
foo = arrFoo.join(' ');
console.log('Ajustamos los espacios', foo);
```

Espero te sirva,

Saludos.

Comment: gracias a sido de mucha ayuda